# backup/restore from-to Gmail?

Tags: iphone, android, lua, gmail

I would like to implement in my app, written in Lua,the option to save a backup file to Gmail and restore it from there.

I just need how to save one file and restore that from the same account again.
Several apps use that feature now ( i guess using the Gmail as HD Feature).

Any ideas? I could read also PHP, Object-C and Java sources if you have nothing in Lua :)

I searched for infos in the net, but did not found a single demo source.

Comment: Neither Java nor Lua are abbreviations; they're proper names.

Answer (score 3):

A google search turned up these IMAP clients:

- [luaimap](http://gitorious.net/luaimap)
- [imapfilter](https://github.com/lefcha/imapfilter)

And from the [Lua mailing list](http://lua-users.org/cgi-bin/namazu.cgi?query=imap&sort=score&idxname=lua-l&max=20)

- [limap](http://www.raschke.pwp.blueyonder.co.uk/limap.c)